# Making text in a JLabel dynamically resize

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager

I have an array of Java Swing JLabels.  The user of my program can add a new JLabel to the JFrame, and I want to make the size of the text in the JLabel change based on the number of JLabels in the frame. If there are too many JLabels, the text will still fit and will not overlap other JLabels.

Comment: OK.. Did you have a question about any of that?  If so, feel free to edit your post and add the questions.  Preferably with an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of what you have already tried.

Comment: The question is what is some good code to Dynamic size the text in the label so the user can add as many as they want labels

Answer (score 2):

Doesnt look pretty, but if that is what you want, here's a quick piece of code to compile and run. Feel free to extract whatever code you need for your project. Have fun, - M.S.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelSize extends JPanel {     

    private Font        font;
    private JPanel      panel;
    private JLabel      label = new JLabel ("Font Size Adapter Label", JLabel.CENTER);
    private JTextField  tf = new JTextField ("Type in text for new label here and hit [Enter]");

    public LabelSize() {         
        super (new BorderLayout());
        panel = labelPanel();
        add (panel, "North");
        add (tf, "South");
        tf.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText (tf.getText());
                label.setFont (font);
                int labelW = (int) Math.ceil (label.getPreferredSize().getWidth());
                int maxWidth = (int) Math.floor (panel.getSize().getWidth());
                if (labelW <= maxWidth)
                    return;
                for (int k = 1 ; labelW > maxWidth ; k++) {
                    Font labelFont = font.deriveFont (font.getSize() - k*1.0f);
                    label.setFont (labelFont);
                    labelW = (int) Math.ceil (label.getPreferredSize().getWidth());
        }}});
    } 

    private JPanel labelPanel() {
        JPanel lp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        lp.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (270,30));
        lp.add (label, "North");
        font = label.getFont();
        return lp;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame lsFrame = new JFrame ("Lfit");
        lsFrame.add (new LabelSize());
        lsFrame.pack();
        lsFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        lsFrame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but yea none that is working for me, i need something that resizes based on size of the Jlabel

Comment: You are welcome, and sorry, I don't understand the coment - which part of the code is not working? I just copied-n-pasted it on an editor, saved, compiled and ran it, runs just fine. May be I did not get your question right - which component (something) did you want resized? Did you want the JLabels to be of fixed (default) font?